# How to get a web element with a class attribute with several values

Tags: html, xml, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, console

This is my problem: i have this html
[image]

as you can see there are two `<div class="sc-fjhmcy dbJOiq flight-information"></div>` and, i want to get the element using the class attribute, but only with the flight-information value, because
I think the part that is written as nonsense code ("sc-fjhmcy dbJOiq...) change daily

I have already tried with this xmlpath, `$x('//div[contains(@class, "flight-information)"']`, but its not working,
What could I do?...

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and I think that there is no big issue with this.
You need to use one class name to get the element, not two names, as below.
$(".sc-fjhmcy")
Then, this will be run correctly.
Best regards